# NixOS rebuild fails because some directories according to NIX_PATH do not exist

Tags: linux, nixos, software-updates, nix

When I try to rebuild NixOS, it fails because it can't find some directories according to `NIX_PATH`. This happens since I tried to switch to the channel `nixos-unstable` from `23.11` and accidentally added also `nixpkgs-unstable` and then removed it. Adding the channel back didn't change the error.

What is wrong here?

The directory `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels` contains only one file, `manifest.nix`, and there are sibling directories `channel-2-link` and `channels-1-link` containing much more including the directory `nixos`.

`NIX_PATH`, my channels and the whole error report are here:

```
~> $env.NIX_PATH
nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels

~> sudo nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable

~> sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade
warning: Nix search path entry '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos' does not exist, ignoring
error:
       … <borked>

         at «none»:0: (source not available)

       … while calling the 'import' builtin

         at «string»:1:6:

            1| with import <nixpkgs/nixos> {}; config.system.build.nixos-rebuild
             |      ^

       (stack trace truncated; use '--show-trace' to show the full trace)

       error: file 'nixpkgs/nixos' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

       at «none»:0: (source not available)
building Nix...
warning: Nix search path entry '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixpkgs/nixos' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

       at «none»:0: (source not available)
warning: Nix search path entry '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixpkgs' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

       at «none»:0: (source not available)
warning: Nix search path entry '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixpkgs/nixos/modules/installer/tools/nix-fallback-paths.nix' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

       at «none»:0: (source not available)
/tmp/nixos-rebuild.TFvl5H/nix
warning: Nix search path entry '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixpkgs' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

       at «none»:0: (source not available)
building the system configuration...
warning: Nix search path entry '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixpkgs/nixos' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

       at «none»:0: (source not available)
```

Comment: You cannot mix branches/channels `--list` points to unstable, while `--upgrade` is still looking for stable..  Try `--add` and re-add stable then `--remove` unstable then update stable then add unstable and remove stable... See the [man page](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/nix-channel.html).  Never manually delete something the package manager is in charge of.  The `manifest` file needs updating.  By deleting the directory, you short circuited the update/channel change

Comment: @eyoung100 I didn't manually delete anything here. Adding a channel automatically removes the previous channel, so I can't `--remove` it later. I don't know how `manifest` is related to that and how to update it. I don't know how what you have written here corresponds to what happens to me or is written on the linked man page. Anyway, `sudo nix-channel --rollback 1` helped.

Comment: A manifest file is normally a list of checksums for all the items installed.  Every time you perform an operation with any of the package manager commands, the manifest is checked or rewritten

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what exactly is wrong here, but I read in [the manual for `nix-channel`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/nix-channel.html) that I can run `sudo nix-channel --rollback` to return to the previous correct state of Nix channels. That solved my issue.